# Detect active tab using Jinja2?

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I'm making a Flask Webapp and I have the following tab content:

```
<div class="tab-content">
   <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="gable">  
       {% include 'building_form.html' %}
   </div>
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="shed">  
       {% include 'building_form.html' %}
   </div>
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="flat">  
       {% include 'building_form.html' %}
   </div>
</div>
```

The code for building_form.html is:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

    <div class="form-group label-floating">
        {{ wtf.form_field(form.width) }}<br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
        {{ wtf.form_field(form.length) }}<br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
        {{ wtf.form_field(form.bottom_height) }}<br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
        {{ wtf.form_field(form.top_height) }}<br>
    </div>
    {% if ???? %} <!--What put here?-->
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
        {{ wtf.form_field(form.ridge_height) }}<br>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
<p><input type=submit value="Calcular"></p>
</form>
```

I´m only want to render the "form.ridge_height" when id="gable" is active. It is posible to do it using Jinja2?

Comment: Did you manage to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the below, it may not work out of the box though! You can pass variables into includes when they're wrapped using `with`. You may need to set up another CSS class called hidden if you haven't got one already, which can be done like this:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

{% with gable = True %}
    {% include 'building_form.html' %}
{% endwith %}
```

And then within the building_form:

```
<div class="form-group label-floating {{ '' if gable == True else 'hidden' }}">
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.ridge_height) }}<br>
</div>
```